# How to use Search multiple LIKE for IN condition in DB2

Tags: sql, select, db2, sql-like, in-operator

```
  SELECT *
  FROM XYZ
  WHERE column1 IN (X1,Y1,Z1);
```

I want to use **LIKE** with this select query; how can I write **LIKE** statement with **IN**, similar to the query as below:

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM XYZ 
  WHERE column1 LIKE IN  ($P{COLUMN});
```

**ANOTHER EXAMPLE:-**

> select * from ( select REPLACE(REFEV_VEH_TYPE, ' ', '') ||
>   REPLACE(REFEV_CATEGORY, ' ', '') || REPLACE(REFEV_USAGE, ' ', '') ||
>   REPLACE(REFEV_BODY_CODE, ' ', '') as  UC  from TREF_ENF_VEHICLE_TYPE )
>   aa where   aa.UC  LIKE ('%06TBISUM%')

```
UC
------
06TBISUM
```

> select * from ( select REPLACE(REFEV_VEH_TYPE, ' ', '') ||
>   REPLACE(REFEV_CATEGORY, ' ', '') || REPLACE(REFEV_USAGE, ' ', '') ||
>   REPLACE(REFEV_BODY_CODE, ' ', '') as  UC  from TREF_ENF_VEHICLE_TYPE )
>   aa where   aa.UC  LIKE ('%B')

```
 UC
----------
06TGISJB
06TGITJB
```

> select * from ( select REPLACE(REFEV_VEH_TYPE, ' ', '') ||
>   REPLACE(REFEV_CATEGORY, ' ', '') || REPLACE(REFEV_USAGE, ' ', '') ||
>   REPLACE(REFEV_BODY_CODE, ' ', '') as  UC  from TREF_ENF_VEHICLE_TYPE )
>   aa where   aa.UC  LIKE ('%BAS')

```
UC
----------
06BCIBAS
05BCABAS
05BCBBAS
```

**The result that i want to know is :**

select * from (
select REPLACE(REFEV_VEH_TYPE, ' ', '') || REPLACE(REFEV_CATEGORY, ' ', '') || REPLACE(REFEV_USAGE, ' ', '') || REPLACE(REFEV_BODY_CODE, ' ', '') as  UC 
from TREF_ENF_VEHICLE_TYPE ) aa
where   aa.UC IN LIKE (**'%06TBISUM%', '%B','%BAS'**).

```
UC
------
06TBISUM
06TGISJB
06TGITJB
06BCIBAS
05BCABAS
05BCBBAS
```

The parameter that i use is **$P{COLUMN}**.
i want to search multiple by **$P{COLUMN}** parameter using IN LIKE($P{COLUMN}).Anyone know about this?

Comment: What do you want to happen if a particular row contains multiple search terms (both `'X1'` _and_ `'Y1'`, say)?

Comment: The result that i want to know is when i put more than one LIKE IN($P{'%06TBISUM%', '%B','%BAS'}).So i want the result show following the 3 LIKE as above.

Comment: ...you may want to use `TRIM(...)` instead of `REPLACE(...)` - you're trying to get rid of leading/trailing spaces, right?  Also, it'd probably be faster to run the `LIKE`s against the source columns, if possible (you're still not going to be able to use an index for it, though).

Comment: ok.but in DB2,i can't use the trim().but my question now is how to get the multiple LIKE result using IN condition?.Can you check my sql?. what's the mistake?.

Comment: Your first problem is that you're attempting to use a single variable as an array, which DB2 doesn't really support.  It thinks you want to look for a single string value, including commas, and of course nothing matches.  If you [split it to a table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17795712/passing-comma-separated-value-as-an-in-parameter-in-stored-procedure/17806998#17806998), that would work better (it can then be used like I do in my answer).  There's ways to do the split wither a vanilla recursive CTE (and I've done it), but I can't quite remember how I did it.

Answer (score 1):

A LIKE operation is functionally equivalent to multiple OR operations. 
So..

```
  SELECT *
  FROM XYZ
  WHERE ( column1 like 'X1' OR column1 like 'X2' OR column1 like 'X3' )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

where REGEXP_LIKE(aa.UC,'.+[06TBISUM.*|B|BAS].+')

Replace + with * (if I put * in it translates to italics)

Answer (score 0):

Another way simplified is use the `IN ('a','b','c')` like that:

```
select *
from tableA
where name IN ('Alberto','Chapote');
```

You can put some arguments as you want inside the ().

Answer (score -1):

You can't use a single variable as an array in DB2, but you can [split it with a recursive CTE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17795712/passing-comma-separated-value-as-an-in-parameter-in-stored-procedure/17806998#17806998).

Here's a version without needing to define a function:

```
WITH Split AS (SELECT '' AS value, txt, LOCATE(',', txt) AS nxt
               FROM (VALUES($P{COLUMN})) t(txt)
               UNION ALL
               SELECT DECODE(nxt, 0, txt, SUBSTR(txt, 1, nxt - 1)),
                      DECODE(nxt, 0, '', SUBSTR(txt, nxt + 1)),
                      DECODE(txt, '', 0, LOCATE(',', txt, nxt + 1))
               FROM Split
               WHERE LENGTH(txt) > 0), 

     SearchData AS (SELECT value
                    FROM Split
                    WHERE value <> '')

SELECT uc
FROM (SELECT REPLACE(refev_veh_type, ' ', '') 
              || REPLACE(refev_category, ' ', '') 
              || REPLACE(refev_usage, ' ', '') 
              || REPLACE(refev_body_code, ' ', '') AS uc
      FROM TRef_ENF_Vehicle_Type ) T
JOIN SearchData
  ON T.uc LIKE SearchData.value
```

(not tested, as I don't have a DB2 instance handy)

`$P{COLUMN}` is assumed to contain the following string: `'%06TBISUM%,%B,%BAS'`.

Comment: i have try the sql in my DB2 but it got the error.Can you correct again you sql?. the error more to VALUES($P{COLUMN}). i have put your value '%06TBISUM%,%B,%BAS' but the result still error. so i don't know the result how look like.can you make the dummy sql so that i understand you sql in DB2

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "dummy" (if you meant a fiddle, it doesn't support DB2 - think I might have tested it against PostgreSQL or Oracle).  I don't know how you're calling this, which might be part of the problem.  You can't just say "there's an error", what error?

Comment: The message error that i get is "DB2
SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC='%06TBISUM%,%B,%BAS';;<IDENTIFIER>,
DRIVER=3.57.82
Error Code: -104"

Comment: `-104` seems to be complaining about the way you're replacing the variable.  I was assuming you were using prepared statements, which would make this a non-issue, besides closing an SQL Injection point.  From the look of it, you've put in the value directly, without designating it as a string (that is, you didn't put in the `'` - the apostrophes).  DB2 looks at it and goes "hunh?".