# how to pass multi-valued parameter in where clause in db2?

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, db2

I have two parameters in a report

1.Location

2.Id

{Location} takes just a single value, where as {Id} takes multiple values

When i write the following query

```
Select Emp_Name, Salary, Manager from Employee_Details
where Emp_Location = {Location}
```

It works absolutely fine.

but when i pass the parameter with multiple values in where clause, the code gives error.

```
Select Emp_Name, Salary, Manager from Employee_Details
where Emp_ID in {ID}
```

How to pass a parameter with multiple values in the where clause?

Comment: A parameter cannot have multiple values.

Comment: You have two options: 1) Dynamic SQL, or 2) pass a [delimited parameter you split to a table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17795712/passing-comma-separated-value-as-an-in-parameter-in-stored-procedure/17806998#17806998) (which you can `SELECT` from, or `JOIN` to).