# Change comma Separated String into comma Separated Integers to use in IN Clause in DB2

Tags: db2

I have a string in DB2 '1,2,3,45,64'. I want to use it in IN Clause like:

```
Select * from table_name where column_name in (1,2,3,45,64)
```

But '1,2,3,45,64' act as a String and throws

> "Invalid character found in a character string argument of the
>   function "DECFLOAT". SQLSTATE=22018"

Comment: is value stored in table with single quote?

Comment: No, Just the datatype of Column is varchar(25)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing comma separated value as an IN parameter in stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17795712/passing-comma-separated-value-as-an-in-parameter-in-stored-procedure)

Comment: You can use `XMLTABLE` and change the comma separated string to  simple XML.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use locate function to find column  value in your string , you will have to add extra comma at beginning and the end to avoid case when 1 and 21 could be the match for value of 1. Basically if you have value 2 in your column you are looking for ',2,' substring in your string. If function find's substring it returns it's starting position otherwise return's -1.

```
Select * from table_name where locate(','||column_name||',',',1,2,3,45,64,')>0
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
Select * from table_name 
where ',' || '1,2,3,45,64' || ',' like '%,' || yourcolumn || ',%'
```