# LISTAGG in WHERE Clause

Tags: sql, db2

I need a query something like

```
select id,name from sample
where 
(:test IS NULL
 OR name IN (:test))
)
```

Is this possible? I don't want to use inner queries.

Comment: Please include some sample data which helps to explain your question.  I don't follow what you are trying to do here.

Comment: I want to filter query using query param :test which is a coma separated values. For example I have names column with values 'ex1','ex2','ex3'. I need to get all the ids and names from table where names in ('ex1','ex2'). So, the output will give 2 rows with names ex1 and ex2.

Comment: whether :test is  null or name in (:test ),, it will give all the rows!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing comma separated value as an IN parameter in stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17795712/passing-comma-separated-value-as-an-in-parameter-in-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 1):

you cant use listagg in IN because it need s a resulset  of one column only to match with, that wont work.
try a simple one:

```
select id,name from sample
where :test is null or
:test  in (select name from sample);
```

from  the where clause of your it looks you will want jus t all the id, names from the table.
whether :test is null or name in (:test ), it will give all the rows!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT id, name
FROM sample
WHERE :test LIKE CONCAT('%,', CONCAT(name, ',%'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create some "string tokenizer" table function. It may be useful for other algorithms as well.

```
create function regexp_tokenize(
  source clob(2M)
, pattern varchar(128))
returns table (seq int, tok varchar(4000))
contains sql
deterministic
no external action
return
select seq, tok
from xmltable('for $id in tokenize($s, $p) return <i>{string($id)}</i>' 
passing 
  source as "s"
, pattern as "p"
columns 
  seq for ordinality
, tok varchar(4000) path '.'
) t;
```

Now we can do the following:

```
with sample (id, name) as (values
 (1, 'ex1')
,(2, 'ex2')
,(3, 'ex3')
)
select s.*
from sample s
join table(regexp_tokenize(coalesce('ex1,ex2', s.name), ',')) f on f.tok=s.name
--join table(regexp_tokenize(coalesce(cast(null as varchar(10)), s.name), ',')) f on f.tok=s.name
--join table(regexp_tokenize(coalesce(:test, s.name), ',')) f on f.tok=s.name
;
```

Actually, it's better to construct different statements for NULL and NOT NULL input due to performance reasons.